# Building an OS Layer with enforced restrictions?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I am attempting to build an OS layer in a project, to provide OS-independent functions to other source codes.  For example, I might have functions like os_calloc, os_free, etc.  I don't think those are very OS-dependent, but feel free to think of better examples.

Currently we have a system that's set up like so:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
void * os_calloc(){
//Windows implementation
}
void * os_free(){
//Windows implementation
}
#endif
#ifdef LINUX
void * os_calloc(){
//Linux implementation
}
void * os_free(){
//Linuximplementation
}
#endif
```

Now, this doesn't sit right to me.  The main reason is that in theory we want to define a set of OS-independent functions and have the exact same set on every system, just with different implementations.

Can this strict relationship be enforced through any programming patterns?  That is, the rule saying "each os implementation must implement this set of functions, no more no less".

EDIT: Let me just make it clear that I'm asking how this relationship can be enforced through design/programming patterns, not for links to other OS-independent libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce something then create an interface class called "IOsInterface" (or similar) that describes the required interface. Any actual OS implementations must fulfill this contract, ie. inherits from the interface class and implements all of the virtual methods.

```
class IOsInterface
{
    public:
        virtual ~IOsInterface() {}
        virtual void * calloc() = 0;
};


class OsWindowsImpl : public IOsInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void * calloc()
        {
            //Windows implementation
        }
};
```

Create a single instance (Singleton, you can't do static virtuals) and use that as the programmatic interface for functionality that uses the OS methods.

Having worked with a home-grown OS-independence layer (Windows, Linux, Solaris Sparc, Solaris X86, and both 32- and 64-bit implementations of each), however, please consider what you are doing very carefully... :-) Boost, QT, APR, all of those are very viable options. Only if your company has a strict policy that everything must be created in-house is this a good idea, I think.

Comment: This is fine, and @Scott I think you did a good job of answering his question. I don't like it though. I don't see why you need the overhead of virtual calls, when this should be a compile-time decision.  You just need to implement the functions with the same name, and then build the proper file at compile time.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Correct, and I wouldn't do this at all, quite frankly. As I said, there are so many libraries that already do this, with hundreds or thousands of users, all finding bugs and reporting bugs and improving the usability and tuning the performance... cross-platform independence is a more or less solved problem, and given the complexity of this particular problem, one that is fraught with enormous difficulty to do correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are already C++ libraries providing that. For example [QtCore](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtcore.html) part of Qt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can work like this. But why invent the wheel? This is what the [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/) does. (The site appears to be down right this minute.) Some OS-independent things APR provides (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Portable_Runtime)):

- Memory allocation and memory pool functionality
- Atomic operations
- Dynamic library handling
- File I/O
- Command-argument parsing
- Locking
- Hash tables and arrays
- Mmap functionality
- Network sockets and protocols
- Thread, process and mutex functionality
- Shared memory functionality
- Time routines
- User and group ID services

Comment: I appreciate your input, but it's not in any way an answer to my question.  I asked how something could be done, and instead to simply pointed me to someone who had done it.  Just because APR is out there doesn't make it right for all cases.

Comment: Well that's your answer to how it could be done. It's open-source, learn from others. Isn't that the point?

Comment: You do just as they do - define the API by identifying common required functionality, and then implementing it in each OS scenario. The trick is to make sure the API is suitable for all implementations. It may need massaging as you implement each case.